# Group_by highschool_name in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying group ever User friends by highschool, the user signs in with his facebook account, I use facebook graph to get all his friends.

This code here outputs/print first all User friends and prints the groups every friend by highschool. I dont want that, I only want it to output/print the groups.

```
<ul class="friends-list">
<% current_user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name).map do |hsname, friends| %>
   <li><%= hsname %></li> 
   <% friends.map do |friend| %>
   <%= image_tag(friend.image) %> 
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

The User tabel:

```
[id, name, image, location, highschool_name, highschool_year, college_name, college_year, graduteschool_name, graduate_year ]
```

The Friend tabel:

```
[id, uid, name, image, higschool_name, college_name, graduateschool_name, user_id]
```

The current output in more details:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-16 01:10:17 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered users/_profile_content.html.erb (0.6ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Friend Load (9.2ms)  SELECT "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."user_id" = 1
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (287.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 321ms (Views: 309.3ms | ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)
```

A image of the output:
http://postimage.org/image/tgyl9f27n/

Comment: Can you post the current output?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra, The current output print all friends the user have and then prints groups of higshchool ... check my update.

Comment: Yep, I understand. Can you show us the actual ERB output? I.e. what your page renders?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra  it renders this: http://postimage.org/image/tgyl9f27n/

Comment: It seems like a templating issue.. I don't know anything about the FB graph plugin however.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra, but I have saved every url of a friend user in the database. It doesent connect to the fb graph when showing the users friends.. I think it is the logic of the code that twist the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**
some values in the database that was empty. Gives the error

**The solution:**

```
<% next if hsname.blank? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand your question, but it sounds like you want to list the friends for each group.  If that is correct, I don't think you need that second map function.

I think it should be a for loop maybe.

```
  <% current_user.friends.group_by(&:highschool_name).map do |hsname, friends| %>

       <li><%= hsname %></li> 
        <%for friend in friends%>
           <%= image_tag(friend.image) %> 
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Hope that helps